# How to get Bitmap of MapView from Android Google Maps API V2

Tags: android, bitmap, android-maps-v2

I'm updating my app to the new Android Maps API V2 and ran into a problem when trying to get a bitmap image of the currently shown map. In API V1 I did this like so:

```
Bitmap mBitmap;
MapViwe mMapView;
// ...
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
mMapView.draw(canvas);
```

Whilest in API V1, this got me a bitmap of the map, in API V2, all I get is a black rectangle.

Also with API V2 I'm  using the `MapView`, not the `MapFragment` so this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[GoogleMap.snapshot()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#snapshot%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback%29) method does the job.