# In Android Map v2 API how to get screen image to share?

Tags: android, bitmap, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

It appears that new android map v2 api (which is really cool, third parties can access rotatable maps, etc. thanks google!) DOES NOT allow easy access to the screen image (we'd like to save the screen image for sharing etc)

This question 
[How to get Bitmap of MapView from Android Google Maps API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396587/how-to-get-bitmap-of-mapview-from-android-google-maps-api-v2) says it cannot be done.

**But** this question and answer implies that it is possible [Taking screenshot of Android OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310990/taking-screenshot-of-android-opengl)

Has anyone saved the image of the android map v2?

**An alternative solution/question:** Is there a way to send an intent to the android operating system to have it start the "Take a screenshot" processing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this question and answer implies that it is possible Taking screenshot of Android OpenGL

Only for your own `GLContext`. You do not have the `GLContext` for a `GoogleMap`.

> Is there a way to send an intent to the android operating system to have it start the "Take a screenshot" processing?

Fortunately no, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Apps cannot take screenshots, except with root permissions or on a few security-challenged devices.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  So how would you share the screen content for an android  map v2?  Would it be best to ask the android maps api v2 group to add support for it?  Another option is to instruct the user if you wish to share use your screenshot hotkey, but that seems not good.

Comment: Also for sending the intent to get a screenshot, the operating system can ask the user "do you want a screenshot" this would allow the user to cancel if it were a rogue app. (i think)

Comment: @RalphYozzo: "So how would you share the screen content for an android map v2?" -- I wouldn't, as that would be of dubious legality. "Would it be best to ask the android maps api v2 group to add support for it?" -- you are welcome to do so. I will be rather surprised if they offer one.

Comment: @RalphYozzo: If you found any solution of above problem then please share.

Comment: @zeeshan0026  I cannot find a solution.  It appears that support would need to be added on the Android Google Maps V2 api level.  This seems to be related to the opengl layer and surfaceview that is used by the API.  I apologize.   The only workaround that I see is ask the user to  take a screenshot and share it :)

Comment: You can upvote/star the following feature request for Google to add screenshot support in the API: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4898