# Maps API v2 - no longer possible to draw into canvas?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

With Maps API v1 it were possible to draw `MapView` into canvas. I've used this feature in [my library](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/AndroidSideMenu) to speed up animations.

With Maps API v2 it's seems no longer possible - after drawing canvas contains only control elements (like buttons) and white screen instead of map.

Is there is any workarounds?

Comment: Found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396587/how-to-get-bitmap-of-mapview-from-android-google-maps-api-v2. Current question is exact duplicate.